# Kendo UI. Set name/id for a "child" widget created from a different widget

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When working with Kendo grid one can create the child widgets e.g. custom dropdownlist in the editor or sub-grid in grid's detail template. Manipulating these child elements is more difficult, because they are not given an id or name. Is it feasible to add these attributes during setup? I don't find this in the API. E.g.

```
$("#rebatesGrid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    edit: fnRebateDropDownEditor,
    detailInit: fnRebateGridDetailInit,
    ...
});

function fnRebateDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required name="' + options.field + '" />').appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({ ... ? set id/name ? ...

function fnRebateGridDetailInit = (e) {   
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell)
    .kendoGrid({ ... ? set id/name ? ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it into element.

```
function fnRebateDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required name="' + options.field + '" id="test" />').appendTo(container)
     .kendoDropDownList({ ...
```

Now, dropdown will get id "test".

Comment: in the dropdown example the name attribute is already there, so I see my question is actually not really making sense for this case. Would you know about the other case with detail template, how to set id/name there?

Comment: Well, actually you can change the name _name="' + options.field + '"_ to whatever you want. However options.field is there because it is way how kendo maps value to property in your model. If you do not need to have dropdown linked with your model, you can change it to whatever you want. 
But to answer your question there is no configuration in widget initialization which sets up id/name. One way how to add/change this attribute is in my answer and second is through javascript. The kendo component borrow attributes from element from which it is created.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I got it now, it's pure jquery way not kendo stuff, I did not know about this $('<div/>') way of constructing new element